# Get a diff of two schema snapshots for update CakePHP app

Tags: php, cakephp

Using CakePHP, I have two snapshots. I am looking to get a diff of the two, then generate a non-destructive MySQL update command with that diff.

Here's what I have so far, it returns an alter table MySQL command, however, this will not work as I need to create said table first.

```
    $this->Schema = new CakeSchema();
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->Schema->connection);
    $options = array();
    $Old = $this->Schema->read($options);
    $Schema = $this->Schema->load();
    $compare = $this->Schema->compare($Old, $Schema);
    $contents = array();

    if (empty($table)) {
        foreach ($compare as $table => $changes) {
            $update = $db->alterSchema(array($table => $changes), $table);
        }
    }
    $this->Installer->query($update);
```

Comment: I noticed also, that the console command "cake schema update" does not include the creation of database tables either. Is there an option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema shell will manage all of the diffs for you. You don't really need to jump through any unnecessary hoops. You only need to worry about two things:

1- You always need to keep a generated schema.

```
cake schema generate
```

This is used to not only keep your base schema, but also your snapshots. Then, you can create the database from this.

```
cake schema create
```

This is used when setting up a new installation or for creating non-existant tables in the database. This is destructive and will drop all tables and recreate them. If you want to create a single missing table, you can call it like so:

```
cake schema create app {table_name}
```

2- Always make snapshots of your schema. This will allow non-destructive upgrades to occur to existing databases. You can upgrade your schema like so:

```
cake schema update {#}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to make this a process that can be run by the UI, you can call the shell from a controller. I would structure it like this:

- keep a version number in the code (Bootstrap) keep the users current
- version in the database compare the versions to know if they need to
- upgrade call the upgrade shell for each version requiring upgrade
- have a task for each upgrade version that is called by the upgrade
  shell

This way if someone needs to upgrade through multiple versions, they will all be run in the same upgrade process.